# can gravy be 'atop' potatoes

Tags: word-usage

Can gravy, which has been ladled, be said to be *atop* potatoes?

I would say it can't, but I'd like to see what other speakers have to say.

I understand *to be atop something* to occupy a *position* there, as a house atop a hill, or a hat atop a head.  Strictly speaking, gravy cannot be *positioned* on potatoes (unless the potatoes are mashed and a crater is formed at the top).

Comment: Yeah, for me you've understood it perfectly. *Atop* is the position something must occupy, and since gravy is a liquid, it doesn't stay *atop* the potatoes no matter how hard you try.

Comment: If the gravy has been ladled *on top of* your potatoes it may run down the sides, but the potatoes are still underneath the gravy and the gravy is *on top of* the potatoes even if not all *at **the** top*. Synchronically and diachronically, *atop* = 'on top of'; I see no problem, and neither do some [278 menus, reviewers and bloggers](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22gravy+atop%22&start=288) found by Google.

Comment: It could be atop mashed potatoes, perhaps?

Comment: You could use _atop_ when giving guidance or direction: _Please put some gravy atop my potatoes_. The fact that most of the gravy is destined to run onto the plate is immaterial. That said, I think _on top of_ might work better than _atop of_ when talking about gravy.

Comment: Yes, @StoneyB, but compare: "cooked to your likeness" :-) : https://www.google.com/search?q=cooked+to+your+likeness&oq=cooked+to+your+likeness&aqs=chrome..69i57.4399j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @TRomano I don't think you can fairly impeach the source of an extension of one sense of one word (*atop*) by pointing to egregious confusions of two distinct senses of another word (*like*) in sources of the same category - particularly when the extension is at worst trivial and arguably wholly consistent with historical usage.

Comment: I think it would be fair to say that restaurant menu writing is a *genre* with lots of boilerplate and echoed phrases, e.g. "atop a sesame seed bun" occurs a gazillion times. These uses are written not spoken, which is an important factor when deciding whether the word is acquiring an extended meaning or is simply being unwittingly misused by someone copying catch-phrases. I don't know if I am alone in making this distinction. An `ngram` search for `* atop` yields these top 10: *from atop, perched atop, one atop, sitting atop, sits atop, sat atop, and atop, high atop, placed atop, stood atop*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can put gravy on top of (atop) potatoes; even if the gravy runs off, some of it will still be over the potatoes (whatever soaked in).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps in an exact scientific approach, this is debatable, but for English language purposes, gravy 'atop' potatoes should make sense.

However, as a note, to actually say this in English Spoken Language would not strictly make sense, it is only really something you understand.